# Strong password regular expression that matches any special char

Tags: c#, regex

I need the following check for strong password validation:

- At least 7 chars
- At least 1 uppercase char (A-Z)
- At least 1 number (0-9)
- At least one special char

I found and tweaked a RegEx and it's like this (sorry, I lost the reference...):

```
^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@'#.$;%^&+=!""()*,-/:<>?]).*$
```

It's working in `C#` except for the fact that I need to match any special char, and I really mean *ANY*. In other words, I need that the "special char" be anything **but** numbers and lower/uppercase letters.

## Edit:

For the sake of clarity, let's consider that accents **are** special chars, so `é`, `ñ` and the like should be considered special chars in the context of this question.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use a regular expression for this, because it's easy to break, and obfuscates the actual rules for validation. Why bother? Just write 4 simple string-matching tests.

Comment: I'll try the string-matching method!

Comment: Your rules are limiting the user's choice of characters and instead of helping make the password more secure are making it less so. Why would you force me to use Latin letters only for my password?

Comment: It's the requirements, not me! Sorry...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).*$
```

Comment: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` will match `é`: not a really special char... :)

Comment: He said "anything but numbers and lower/uppercase letters", I think é qualifies.

Comment: I think Bart is trying to say that `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` should match any character that is *not a letter*, but it will match `é` that most certainly *is* a letter (I believe that it will treat other "international" letters like å, ñ and so on as well, which it really shouldn't)

Comment: Tried all others solutions, and this is the only one that worked 100%. I'm really thankful!

Comment: `é` is a lower-case "e" with acute accent. It is by no means a special char.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk, Yuriy got what I was tring to say. I agree that `é` is a character *but* in this case, let's consider it's `special`

Comment: @brunosalvino: sure, if those are the requirements and you are aware of it I see no problem. But I often see this kind of regex suggested where neither the OP nor the person providing the answer are aware of this, in which case they instead introduce a bug (and a rather serious one, in my eyes). That does not seem to be the case here though. (It was not me voting down, BTW)

Answer (score 5):

(Not C# code)

```
def validate (value):
    return (value.Length >= 7 &&
            value.IndexOfAny(['0', ..., '9']) >= 0 &&
            value.IndexOfAny(['A', ..., 'Z']) >= 0 &&
            value.IndexOfAny(['@', ..., ')']));
```

Yes I know this is not what the question required, but I believe it's much clearer, have higher performance and easier to maintain than any RegExp solution.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that :-

\w

Matches any word character.

The inverse is :-

\W

Which is what you want.

**Edit**

```
^.*(?=.{7,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).*$
```

Test your regular expressions at :-

http://www.nregex.com/nregex/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) and pick an Unicode class, like `\p{Symbol}` or `\p{Punctuation}`

Comment: Yes, `\p{Punctuation}` and `\p{Symbol}` is what I'd do. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(?=.{7,})(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[@'#.$;%^&+=!"()*,-/:<>?])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex Rx = null;
            Rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^(?=.*?[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{7,}$");


            if (Rx.IsMatch(textBox3.Text))
            {
                textBox3.BackColor = Color.Green;
                textBox3.ForeColor = Color.White;
                MessageBox.Show("Password is (correct) format ");
            }
            else
            {
                textBox3.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
                textBox3.ForeColor = Color.White;
                MessageBox.Show("Contact is (in-correct) format");

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add some explanations what your code does? For guidance, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: // At least one upper case English letter[A-Z] ^(?=.*?[A-Z])
        // At least one lower case English letter[a-z] (?=.*?[a-z])
        // At least one digit[0-9] (?=.*?[0-9])
        // At least one special character, eight in length (?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$